# Stuck with Android Studio: Using "Double" for Text Watcher

Tags: java, android, android-studio, double, textwatcher

I am currently struggling with this temperature converter app. How this app works is if I type in a number in the blank text, it will calculate to other temperature unit without clicking a button (by Text Watcher)

Here, I need to use Double value to extract the number from the EditText and use that value to make an equation and insert it to the result view. So in this case, I'm using:

```
double tempWantCtoF = 1.8 * tempWhat + 32;
double tempWantFtoC = tempWhat - 32 * 0.55;
```

and tempWhat is the value inserted in the EditText.

App is functional until I type in any number on the Text field and the app crashes to home screen with an error message, "Unfortunately, *APP NAME* has stopped."

I assume it is a problem in using the double value under afterTextChanged from Text Watcher method implementation.

If anyone knows what could lead to the problem, I would really appreciate it.

Here is my main activity XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="josephshin.tempconv.MainActivity"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tempSwitch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tempIndicator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tempSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/c_to_f"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/is"
        android:id="@+id/isLabel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/enter_your_temperature"
        android:id="@+id/tempResult"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isLabel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tempEdit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tempIndicator"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_temperature"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AND THIS IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY JAVA FILE:

```
package josephshin.tempconv;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean CtoF;
double tempWhat;
double tempWantCtoF = 1.8 * tempWhat + 32;
double tempWantFtoC = tempWhat - 32 * 0.55;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Switch tempSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.tempSwitch);
    final TextView tempIndicator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempIndicator);
    final EditText tempLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempEdit);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempResult);


    tempSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                tempIndicator.setText("°F to °C");
                CtoF = false;
            }
            else {
                tempIndicator.setText("°C to °F");
                CtoF = true;
            }
        }
    });
    tempLabel.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable edi) {
            tempWhat = Double.parseDouble(tempLabel.toString());
            if (CtoF){
                result.setText("" + tempWantCtoF);
            }
            if (!CtoF){
                result.setText("" + tempWantFtoC);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

THANK YOU! ps. I am a beginner! just started getting into this but can't seem to find a problem that is similar enough.

EDIT>
logcat for leaving the text box blank

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: josephshin.tempconv, PID: 31895
                                                                     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                         at josephshin.tempconv.MainActivity$2.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:56)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9271)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:12015)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1047)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:564)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:225)
                                                                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:34)
                                                                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:106)
                                                                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:51)
                                                                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:215)
                                                                         at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7187)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6994)
                                                                         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3249)
                                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9838)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2808)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1838)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2977)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:312)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2682)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5273)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5226)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4834)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4891)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4726)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4692)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4700)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4673)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7359)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7237)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7198)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4310)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        a
```

Comment: Try this tempLabel.getText().toString() instead of tempLabel.toString(). And post your logcat message. That would be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: @ajantha thank you for your help! So now it isn't crashing when I type in any number but when I completely leave the text field blank (numberless) back again, it crashes back to home screen with the "app has stopped" message.... ugh I'll post the logcat when the crash occurs for leaving the text box blank.

Comment: Check the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a few mistakes.

Firstly, you should declare `tempWantCtoF` and `tempWantFtoC` as methods, not variables:

```
private double tempWantCtoF() {
    return 1.8 * tempWhat + 32;
}

private double tempWantFtoC() {
    return tempWhat - 32 * 0.55;
}
```

Secondly, to get the text of a `TextView`, don't use `toString`, use `getText().toString()` instead:

```
tempWhat = Double.parseDouble(tempLabel.getText().toString());
```

This is also why the error occurs.

You might also want to add some error handling code:

```
try {
    tempWhat = Double.parseDouble(tempLabel.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now the equation is actually functional and up and running with no crashes. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @ShinJoseph If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Sorry for getting at ya a little late. Been busy coding..... Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty string before converting it into Double.
like this,

```
     if(tempLabel.getText().toString().equals("")){
      tempWhat=0; 
     }else{
      tempWhat = Double.parseDouble(tempLabel.getText().toString());
     }
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! it stopped crashing when the textbox goes back to blank. I really appreciate it!